# Redux Multiple Action Handling

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

How does redux behave when multiple actions are dispatched simultaneously on the same object in the store?

For example, if I have subscriptions to two different data streams and each time I receive data on a stream I execute a handler function. The handler function processes the data and dispatches an action to update the same object in the redux store. If I receive data on both streams at the same time and dispatch the actions at the same time or close to the same time, how does redux handle the state update?

Are the actions processed one at a time in the order they come in or will they be processed at the same time with the potential that the second action could overwrite changes that the first made to the state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript is a single threaded language, so the updates will get stacked and execute one after the other. (you can see them in the call stack).

Comment: This is what I suspected. Thanks for the quick answer.